# Formula that captures the value of a specific cell 1 row down & 1 column over (trending)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I need a formula that takes cell (AX24) and goes down 1 row and over 1 column to return me the value of (AY25).
But I need this formula to then dynamically change so when it is copied down to the next row it takes cell (AY25) and goes down 1 row and over 1 column to return me the value of (AZ26) so on and so forth.

I've tried offsetting but this does not dynamically change the column reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing this in Cell `A1` and starting with an absolute reference to `AX24` you can return `AX24`, `AY25` and `AZ26` using

```
=OFFSET($AX$24,ROW(B1)-1,ROW(B1)-1)
```

And then dragging down.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you sir!

Comment: Happy to have helped!